# How can I get my services to register with a specific port in Eureka?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, aws-security-group

#### My Setup

I have some services that register with Eureka. This registration info is used by Zuul to route requests to my services. Most of these services run on a port like 9999 or 8080. Each service is on it's own EC2 instance, and I have Nginx routing requests from port 80 to the server's port, so that I can keep my Security Group rules simple.

#### My Problem

When my service registers with Eureka, it gets registered with `${server.port}`, which ends up being 8080 or 9999, etc. When Zuul attempts to route to `{ec2host}:8080`, it gets blocked by my Security Group rules. Based on [the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_eureka_metadata_for_instances_and_clients), it looks like I should be able to specify a host and port with `eureka.instance.hostname` and `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort`. Whether I use those properties or not, my service registers with it's specific port.

[image: Registry]

Is there a way to get the Eureka client to register my service with port 80, instead of the server's port?

Comment: What you see there isn't the port that is registered, it's just the id. You'd need to look in `/eureka/apps` to see the actual port. `eureka.instance.nonSecurePort` should work.

Comment: You are correct. I was so focused on getting that to display correctly that I missed the root cause (my nginx service was down).
On a related note, if you want to modify that id, you can set `eureka.instance.instanceId`.